# Mysql, left join and count conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have fallowing SQL query (pseudo query):

```
SELECT 
    some columns [...]
    COUNT(clicks.id) AS clicks,
    COUNT(transactions.id) AS transactions 
FROM 
    campaign
LEFT JOIN   
    clicks ON clicks.key = campaign.key
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        id, key 
    FROM 
        transactions 
    GROUP BY 
        userkey 
    ) transactions ON clicks.key = transactions.key;
GROUP BY
    campaign.id
```

Query return good results. On example:

```
column | columns [..] | 34 | 10
column | columns [..] | 22 | 1
column | columns [..] | 34 | 17
```

So, records in table clicks they have transactions or a few transactions or they do not.

Haw Can I retun COUNT() clicks who have COUNT(transactions.id) = 0 and COUNT(transactions.id) > 0 ? On example:

```
column | columns [..] | 34 | 10 | 4 (count data from clicks table which have related transactions) | 30 (count data from clicks table which not have related transactions)
column | columns [..] | 22 | 1  | 6  | 16
column | columns [..] | 34 | 17 | 10 | 24
```

Tahnks for help.

**@UPDATE:**

I solved my problem adding second table. Now my SQL query looks like:

```
SELECT 
    some columns [...]
    COUNT(clicks.id) AS clicks,
    COUNT(transactions.id) AS transactions,
    COUNT(clicks_count.id) as witchout_transactions, 
    (COUNT(clicks.id) - COUNT(clicks_count.id)) as witch_transactions 
FROM 
    campaign
LEFT JOIN   
    clicks ON clicks.key = campaign.key
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        id, key 
    FROM 
        transactions 
    GROUP BY 
        userkey 
    ) transactions ON clicks.key = transactions.key
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        clicks.id, 
        COUNT(transactions.id) AS transactions 
    FROM 
        clicks 
    LEFT JOIN transactions ON clicks.key = transactions.key 
    GROUP BY clicks.id 
    HAVING transactions = 0
    ) clicks_count ON clicks_count.id = clicks.id 
GROUP BY
    campaign.id
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about adding a second join with the clicks table

```
JOIN (
    SELECT id 
    FROM clicks
    LEFT JOIN transactions ON clicks.key = transactions.key AND transactions.id != 0) clicks2 ON clicks.id = clicks2.id
```

And in the select clause use this to for the two columns

```
SELECT 
    some columns [...]
    COUNT(clicks.id) AS clicks,
    COUNT(transactions.id) AS transactions
    COUNT(clicks2.id) as clicks_with
    clicks - clicks_with AS clicks_without
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you can try to use `CASE WHEN` expression and `COUNT`

Because you didn' provide any sample data and expected result, so I can only provide pseudo-query.

```
SELECT...,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN [have transactions condition] then 1 end),
   COUNT(CASE WHEN [not have related transactions condition] then 1 end)
```

If that didn't help you, you can provide some data and expect result, I will edit my answer.

Comment: That's exactly what I need, but I dont know haw Can I use it in this case... I think that CASE WHEN must be use on clicks table, but this is used like a left join...

Comment: You can try::

COUNT(CASE WHEN transactions.key is null THEN 1 end) withoutClicks, COUNT(CASE WHEN transactions.key is not null THEN 1 end) withClicks